# Como mostrar en una vista los tatos que obtengo con un procedimiento almacenado en mysql con asp .net core 2.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedure, asp.net-core

en asp .net core 2.0 MVC tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo un modelo llamado liquidaciones en los cuales tengo tres variables las cuales son liquidacionesID, campo1 y campo2, asi mismo tengo un procedimiento almacenado en mysql el cual me devuelve esos mismos campos de la base de datos, el problema es que no se como pasar a la vista index de liquidaciones esos datos que estoy obteniendo del procedimiento almacenado, se como ejecutarlo y pasarle parámetros pero no se como obtener lo que viene de respuesta por ejemplo en una tabla o en un input. aquí dejo imagen del procedimiento almacenado el cual esta en mysql creado desde phpmyadmin, cabe decir que ya lo ejecute en la opción que phpmyadmin nos entrega y si estoy obteniendo datos de respuesta.

de antemano muchas gracias por su atencion saludos

buscando e inplementando varias cosas encontre esto  public IActionResult 
pero al momento de correr la pagina me dice que esta no funciona que e sido redirijido muchas veces

```
 public IActionResult Index(Liquidaciones liquidaciones)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = (MySqlConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "consultar";
        var response = new List<Liquidaciones>();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                liquidaciones.LiquidacionesID = (int)reader["liquidacionesID"];
                liquidaciones.campo1 = (string)reader["campo1"];
                liquidaciones.campo1 = (string)reader["campo2"];

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente punto 2, 3 y 4.

Comment: Ya corregí la pregunta

Comment: Defines `var response = new List<Liquidaciones>();` y en ningún lado la utilizas. Luego haces un `RedirectToAction`, con esa lógica, ¿cómo vas a mostrar los datos? Te hace falta mandar a la vista ya sea mediante un modelo, un ViewData, un ViewBag, si recién estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC mira este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Te será de utilidad a pesar que sea de MVC 5 con .net Framework "full", los conceptos son los mismos. Buena suerte

Comment: vale, gracias entonces pasare la variable esponse un viewBag y miro a ver como me va

Comment: Considera que ese `RedirectToAction` hace que el proceso se "pierda", normalmente los RedirectToAction son acompañandos por uno o más `TempData` que contienen los errores o mensajes para el usuario

Comment: entonces la manera correcta seria?

Comment: Del comentario anterior: "Te hace falta mandar a la vista ya sea mediante un modelo, un ViewData, un ViewBag, si recién estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC mira este workshop: youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY "

Comment: recien estoy empezando, mirare el video que me dices pero es algo largo

Comment: o eso, o te tomas un curso de 30 horas aprox como lo hice en su tiempo para resumirlo en 4 horas :D venga que para todo hay un costo, esfuérzate y la haces :) PD: Revisa la documentación oficial, ahí está casi todo, lo que falta está en tomar acciónn :D